# How should I structure my entities and not get the circular reference problem/error?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, relational-database, .net-6.0

I'm trying to establish a one-to-many relationship between entities.

I'm using `.NET 6` with [Entity Framework](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6) code-first approach to model my database. Most of my relations are one-many.

When I tried a request with [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), the response I got back was an error message telling me that it's a circular reference. My objects are referencing each other.

How should I structure my entities and not get the circular reference problem/error?

On the "one" side, there is a navigation property. It contains a foreign key property, such as `entityId`, which establishes a relationship with another entity.

On the "many" side, there is a navigation property of a collection that holds multiple instances.

How I structure my entities and their configurations:

```cs
public class Author
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public Author author { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Genre> Genres{ get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{ 
    public Book Book {get;set;}
    public Guid BookId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class BookEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder) 
    {
        builder.HasOne(b => b.author)
               .WithMany(a => a.Books)
               .HasForeignKey(b => b.AuthorId);
    }
}

public class GenreEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Genre>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Genre> builder) 
    {
        builder.HasOne(g => g.Book)
               .WithMany(b => b.Genres)
               .HasForeignKey(g => g.BookId);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a Genre has only one Book, then you will be able to assign a Genre only once. You need a m:n relation between Books and Genres. But apart from that I don't see a problem in your EF configuration. There may be an issue with the postman (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: How are you returning the data? Do you use a dto or something similar?